# Uneven widget's width even with hard coded width in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am creating a form with simple labels and input field . Below is the layout code

```
child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16,8,0,0),
                child: Text(
                  "Purchase Order : Other Details",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 22,
                      fontFamily: 'Lato',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 150,
                child: Text(
                  'Gate In Date'.toUpperCase(),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black87,
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontFamily: 'Lato',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:8,top: 8),
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 5,
                  borderOnForeground: true,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 240,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 16, right: 16)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 150,
                child: Text(
                  'Gate Out Date'.toUpperCase(),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black87,
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontFamily: 'Lato',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:8,top: 8),
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 5,
                  borderOnForeground: true,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 240,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 16, right: 16)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,),
          Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 150,
                child: Text(
                  'Gate In Time'.toUpperCase(),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black87,
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontFamily: 'Lato',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8,left: 8),
                child: Container(
                  width: 240,
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 5,
                    borderOnForeground: true,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 16, right: 16)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 150,
                child: Text(
                  'Gate Out Time'.toUpperCase(),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black87,
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontFamily: 'Lato',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:8,top: 8),
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 5,
                  borderOnForeground: true,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 240,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 16, right: 16)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:8.0),
            child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start
              ,children: [
                Container(
                  width: 150,
                  child: Text(
                    'Tare Weight'.toUpperCase(),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black87,
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontFamily: 'Lato',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8,left: 8),
                      child: Container(
                        width: 240,
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: Card(
                                elevation: 5,
                                borderOnForeground: true,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black87),
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      border: InputBorder.none,
                                      contentPadding:
                                          EdgeInsets.only(
                                              left: 16,
                                              right: 16)),
                                ),
                              ),flex: 2,
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Card(
                                elevation: 5,
                                borderOnForeground: true,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black87),
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      border: InputBorder.none,
                                      contentPadding:
                                          EdgeInsets.only(
                                              left: 16,
                                              right: 16)),
                                ),
                              ),flex: 1,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 150,
                  child: Text(
                    'Gross Weight'.toUpperCase(),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black87,
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontFamily: 'Lato',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8,left: 8),
                  child: Container(
                    width: 240,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: Card(
                            elevation: 5,
                            borderOnForeground: true,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            child: TextFormField(
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black87),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                  contentPadding:
                                  EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: 16,
                                      right: 16,
                                      )),
                            ),
                          ),flex: 2,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Card(
                            elevation: 5,
                            borderOnForeground: true,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            child: TextFormField(
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black87),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                  contentPadding:
                                  EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: 16,
                                      right: 16,
                                      )),
                            ),
                          ),flex: 1,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start
            ,children: [
              Container(
                width: 150,
                child: Text(
                  ''.toUpperCase(),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black87,
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontFamily: 'Lato',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 240,
                child: Text(''),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                child: Container(
                  width: 150,
                  child: Text(
                    'Net Weight'.toUpperCase(),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black87,
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontFamily: 'Lato',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
                child: Container(
                  width: 240,
                  child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start
                    ,children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Card(
                          elevation: 5,
                          borderOnForeground: true,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: TextFormField(
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black87),
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                contentPadding:
                                EdgeInsets.only(
                                    left: 16,
                                    right: 16,
                                    )),
                          ),
                        ),flex: 2,
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Card(
                          elevation: 5,
                          borderOnForeground: true,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: TextFormField(
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black87),
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                contentPadding:
                                EdgeInsets.only(
                                    left: 16,
                                    right: 16,)),
                          ),
                        ),flex: 1,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      )
```

For every label and input field, I have given same fixed width but still they are not looking equal when I run the app in device

See the attached screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you structure it the other way around Row(Column(), Column, Column, Column)

1st column labels, 2nd fields, 3rd labels, 4th fields